# C Nested Structs Initialization

Tags: c, struct, nested, embedded, esp-idf

I'm an avid embedded c programmer. I recently started working with the ESP IDF framework to program the ESP32. Even though I think that the following code is initializing a struct within a struct (not sure); but for some reason, I cannot grasp how and why there is just a ".mode" rather than the struct's name within gpio_config_t + ".mode". This is just an example but there are several instances of similar types of initialization.

for example:

```
typedef struct example_struct{
int mode;
int pull_up_en;
.
.
}example_struct;

typedef struct gpio_config_t
{
 example_struct test;
} gpio_config_t;
```

Shouldn't the initialization be done the following way?

```
gpio_config_t io_test_config = 
{
test.mode = 3; 
test.pull_up_en = 1; 
etc
};
```

Can someone please clarify this?

The actual type of initialization I'm referring to:

```
gpio_config_t io_conf = {
        .mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT,
        .pull_up_en = 1,
    };
```

Comment: [Common compilers producing errors for the `.mode =` variant.](https://godbolt.org/z/P1W3K7qjs) If your compiler is not, it is allowing code the C standard does not require. C 2018 6.7.9 7 says the identifier in a `.identifier` form should be a member of the *current object*, and 6.7.9 18 tells us the list begins with the current object associated with the closest surrounding brace pair, which would be the `gpio_config_t` that is `io_conf`.

Comment: In the future, always present a [mre] for questions like this. That should be **one** sequence of code that includes definitions for everything used (like `GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT`) that reproduces the problem. Do not put some introductory code with a vertical line of dots and separate, after multiple paragraphs, a second piece of code that needs to go with the first. Show one short concrete example without requiring people to figure out your text to match up one part with another.

Comment: It should be `{.test.mode = 3, .test.pull_up_en = 1}`

Comment: A form defined by the C standard would be `.test.mode = 3, .test.pull_up_en = 1,`, not `test.mode = 3; test.pull_up_en = 1;`. And so, by having multiple differences between the two variants, you confuse the question being asked. The first form has a member name for the current object, `test`, whereas the other starts with a submember, `mode`. The first form does not start with a `.`, but the second form does. The first form has `;` but the second form has `,`. So which of these differences are you asking about? Does either form work for you? With what compiler?

Comment: Or `{.test = {.mode = 3, .pull_up_en = 1}}`

Comment: Edit your post to clarify the question. Present one sequence of code that reproduces the issue with the form you think should not work. Test it in your compiler to be sure. Report the results. Present a second sequence that shows the form you think should work. Test it in your compiler and report the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical term for the notation you're using is [designated initializers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9).  The designators always start with either a `.` or a `[`, and there are no semicolons in the initializers (until after the `}` at the end of the [initializer](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7)).  There are many ways that you could initialize that structure, including:

```c
gpio_config_t io_test_config1 = 
{
    .test.mode = 3, .test.pull_up_en = 1
};

gpio_config_t io_test_config2 = 
{
    .test = { .mode = 3, .pull_up_en = 1 }
};

gpio_config_t io_test_config3 = 
{
    { 3, 1 }
};

gpio_config_t io_test_config4 = 
{
    3, 1 
};
```

The last one doesn't compile cleanly with GCC when you specify `-Wmissing-braces` (usually activated by `-Wall`).